# Swift 2: Method for giving all sprites spawned a change in velocity

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am spawning a new sprite every 4 second with a NSTimer. This is the sprite code:

```
    enemy1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: enemyTexture)
    enemy1.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 300, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 300)
    enemy1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: enemyTexture, size: enemyTexture.size())
    enemy1.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    enemy1.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
    enemy1.setScale(0.4)
    self.addChild(enemy1)
```

I am looking for a method to give all the enemy1 sprite a velocity like this whenever i want to:

```
   enemy1.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(70, 0)
```

I want the velocity to stay the same until i decide to change it and i do that by adding the code in the update function.

So my question is how can i give a constant velocity to all spawned sprites?

Comment: Whirlwind answer is what you are looking for. As a tip it's better to use SKAction.waitforduration instead of NSTimers when making SpriteKit games. NSTimers don't get cancelled properly on scene transitions, they don't pause when you pause your scene etc.

Answer (score 2):

Name your sprites like this:

```
enemy1.name = "enemy1"
```

Then enumerate nodes by name, like this:

```
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("enemy1") { node, stop in

     //do your stuff here  
}
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comments... You name your nodes right where you create them. Just before you add them to the scene. Where you should enumerate your nodes it depends on what you want to achieve. If you want to change their velocity on touch, then do it inside of touchesBegan. If you want to do same task every frame, then you do it in update method.

Comment: Where should I add the:  enemy1.name = "enemy1"?  and do i add the enumeration in the update func?